# User Policy Problem When I define two User models

Tags: laravel, model, policy

I'm using Policies in Laravel. When I use two user models in policy it would not access me! However, both `$user` and `$player` return me correct data, individually. How can I handle it? What is my mistake?

in Controller:

```
$this->authorize('modifyTournamentRegistration', $player);
```

in Policy:

```
public function modifyTournamentRegistration(User $user, User $player)
    {
        return $user->id === $player->id || $user->inRole('admin');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is because of Input variable type in Policy. I added User class in AuthServiceProvider:

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];
```

Then, I defined the function in UserPolicy:

```
public function modifyPlayerTournamentRegistration(User $user, User $player)
    {
        return $player->id === $user->id || $user->inRole('admin');
    }
```

And used it in Controller:

```
$this->authorize('modifyTournamentRegistration', $player);
```

It works as well :)